# Python subprocess: How to run a python script using a different intepreter than the main thread

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running an application that has an embedded python interpreter which is 2.7. I need to run a standalone python application as a subprocess, but that application is only compatible with python 2.6. How can I force the python application to launch with the python2.6 interpreter?

Comment: Is python 2.6 installed? Where is the python 2.6 executable?

Comment: Make the first argument to `Popen` `['path/to/python2.6', 'themodule.py']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A few complications, the python script is not a .py script, but a wrapper bash executable (with #! /usr/bin/env python2).

To run the script using python2.6, you could change its shebang to point to python2.6 executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
```

and run the script directly:

```
subprocess.check_call(['/path/to/your_script'] + sys.argv[1:])
```

`sys.argv[1:]` is used to pass command-line arguments to the child script.

If you can't change the shebang then run:

```
subprocess.check_call(['/usr/bin/env', 'python2.6', '/path/to/your_script'] + 
                      sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 3):

Like Dunes already said:

```
proc = Popen(['/path/to/executable', '-flag1', '--opt=value'])
```

The executable could be Python script with the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python2.6` or a bash script starting your Python2.6 interpreter.

Note, that the interpreter will not wait for the 2.6 version to finish. You have to use the `.wait()` method for that. Otherwise your child process can become a zombie.

```
# wait for the process to finish
proc.wait()
```

If you want to create a daemon - meaning a child process that does not terminates if the parent is killed - you need the `os.fork()` function. There are scripts around that takes care of all the stuff for you - eg. [daemonize.py](https://github.com/lfittl/python-helpers/blob/master/daemonize.py)

Comment: A few complications, the python script is not a .py script, but a wrapper bash executable (with #! /usr/bin/env python2). Also, there are a lot of arguments to the process, and python is identifying them as its own arguments. Any ideas on how to avoid this?

Comment: @user443850: update your question or ask a new one. Don't put new information regarding your question in a comment.